# How to store data from android to amazon s3

Tags: android, amazon-s3

Thanks for previous replies.

I want to store images that is residing in my sdcard to amazon s3 cloud. i have no idea to share the data from android to amazon, if anyone having idea, pls guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want to upload the pictures then there are several apps in the market.

If you want to transfer the data programmatically then you can use the AWS SDK:

http://aws.amazon.com/de/sdkforandroid/

Comment: Thank you, i downloaded aws-android-sdk, but i dont know what i will do on that..

Comment: There is a online documentation with examples: `http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4225549089557252`

Comment: I included jar file with my android application, can you guide me how to connect android application with amazon s3. I referred website for more than a day, i cant able to find out proper examples. if you have any samples pls kindly share. thanks in advance.

Comment: Please refer to the `AWSAndroidDemo` inside the `samples` folder of the aws-android-sdk. It will provide all the necesary information.

Comment: Thank you, i am verifying that document.

Comment: Do you know how to upload a file in s3, because in that example they dint specify uploading concept.